# Tasks not reaching Celery from Flask, but only when called from a Flask app route

Tags: python, flask, rabbitmq, celery

I am using Celery to set up a task queue that is called from a simple Flask API. However, I'm running into some strange behaviour where Celery is not working when called from within a route in the Flask app.

I've reduced the code to the following while still getting the same error.

```py
from celery import Celery

import env_config as cfg

from flask import Flask


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.update(
    CELERY_BROKER_URL='pyamqp://guest@localhost//',
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='rpc://'
)


def make_celery(app):
    celery = Celery(
        app.name,
        backend=app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'],
        broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL']
    )

    class ContextTask(celery.Task):
        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return self.run(*args, **kwargs)

    celery.Task = ContextTask
    return celery


celery = make_celery(app)


@celery.task
def predict_job(job_id):
    # do nothing
    pass


@app.route('/predict_job', methods=['GET'])
def predict_job_route():
    predict_job.delay(1)
    return 'processing'


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Flask app is working."


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=False, host=cfg.ML_HOST, port=cfg.ML_PORT)
```

There is zero response from either the Celery or the Flask logs.
I can access the '/' route normally and see the GET request in the Flask logs. I.e.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Jun/2019 13:34:45] "[37mGET / HTTP/1.1[0m" 200 -
```

Now here's the interesting thing. If I modify the code with the following:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    predict_job.delay(1)
    app.run(debug=False, host=cfg.ML_HOST, port=cfg.ML_PORT)
```

Then not only does this second predict_job.delay() run exactly as expected, but now the original predict_job.delay() works fine when accessed via the route.

For reference here is the successful Celery logging:

```
[2019-06-12 13:41:30,464: INFO/MainProcess] Task app.predict_job[25a37d95-2060-4d8a-abff-c4d18804c03d] succeeded in 0.0s: None
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a line after your `make_celery` call:

```
celery = make_celery(app)
celery.conf.update(app.config)
```

(Check the [configuration example from Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/celery/#configure) - as you can see, you could also do this within the `make_celery` function)

Additionally, make sure to [run a celery worker](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/celery/#run-a-worker).

Comment: I tried that but it didn't make a difference. There are changes to Celery since the Flask configuration example was given.
I am running a worker and I've tried a couple different configuration options with it to see if anything works. Keep in mind that everything works if I put that one line in before `app.run`.